# Redirect on successful Login using servicestack

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I've recently decided to migrate over to using servicestack authentication. From what I can tell, to have a redirect after a successful login of an oauth provider, you add the url to the appSettings of your web.config, i.e. oauth.GoogleOpenId.RedirectUrl.

My question is, is there anyway to make this more dynamic so that if a user get's redirected to the log on page when trying to access an authorized page, say their profile page, that once they log on successfully they get routed to their profile page instead of what's configured in the web.config?  Forms authentication did this by using a 'returnUrl' query parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of accessing a protected page, redirecting to a `/login` page (overridable with HtmlRedirect on AuthFeature or Authenticate attribute) and on successful login should automatically redirect to the previously attempted protected page.

To do this you want to specify the redirect url in the `continue` or `ReturnUrl` FormData POST variable or QueryString when attempting to authenticate with the `/auth` service.

Comment: is this still the case with the latest ServiceStack implementation? Cannot see documentation/references to the Continue variable. What is recommended approach using latest version?

Comment: @Mark Yeah you can still use `continue` or `ReturnUrl` Request Params.